# Laravel validation Using Closures

Tags: validation, laravel-5

Developing with Laravel 5.4 I am trying the example from Laravel documentation:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
'title' => [
    'required',
    'max:255',
    function($attribute, $value, $fail) {
        if ($value === 'foo') {
            return $fail($attribute.' is invalid.');
        }
    },
],
```

]);

I am getting this error:

Object of class Closure could not be converted to string

Why?

Answer (score 4):

In 5.4 if you wan't a closure you can pass it after the validation rules, like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'title' => ['required', 'max:255'],
]);

$validator->after(function ($validator) {
    if ($request->get('field') === 'foo') {
        $validator->errors()->add('field', 'Field is invalid.');
    }
});

if ($validator->fails()) {
    //
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In **Laravel 5.4** this does not work. You need to update to **Laravel 5.6**, or at least have **"illuminate/validation"** **version 5.6**