# how to call laravel validation rules in a closure function in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I wish to skip the captcha validation if  the account,which maybe  a email or mobile, has been captcha validated.

so I write a colsure function. if the session('captcha_validated_reset_account') equals to the account which user input, it will skip the captcha validation.

if not, the program will  call a laravel  validation rule like "required|captcha"(captcha' comes from https://github.com/mewebstudio/captcha).

The problem is I don't know how to call validation rule in a closure,I tried return 'required|captcha' but it not work as intended.

```php
'captcha' => function($attribute, $val, $fail) use ($request) {
    if (
        ! empty(session('captcha_validated_reset_account'))
        && session('captcha_validated_reset_account') == $request->input('account')
    ) {
        return;
    } else {
        Rule::required... //and call a rule named 'captcha' to validate the captcha code from user input
        //return 'required|captcha';
    }
}
```

Is any way I can call laravel validation rules in a closure function?

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49127909/laravel-validation-using-closures You gotta have laravel 5.6+ to make it happen.

Answer (score 3):

You should put the closure in an array:

```php
'captcha' => [ function ($attribute, $val, $fail) use ($request) {
    if (
        empty(session('captcha_validated_reset_account'))
        && session('captcha_validated_reset_account') != $request->input('account')
    ) {
        $fail($attribute . ' is required.');
    }
}]
```

Note that I've changed the condition.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, please notice I wish to call  a rule named "captcha" which will validate the captcha code from user input.  I don't know how to call this rule in a closure.

Comment: oh, sorry I thought that's the name of the filed you are validating. In that case you will need a custom rule, or extend the captcha rule from the library that you are using and override it's `passes` method to apply your condition.

Comment: or check if you can do `Rule::captcha(function() {});`